# Why does the strange value come out with an unnecessary % conversion in the code in C language?

Tags: c, xcode

I started learning programming only few days ago, so basically I have no knowledge.

I'm starting with C, and I wrote a very simple code which is:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    printf("%d + %d", 1 + 3);
    return 0;
}
```

with the code above, I got the value of 4 + 1606416608 and later found that the return value is wrong because I put more %d than necessary. Then my question is, how did that strange value actually come out? If anyone knows, please help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Required arguments does not match. So `printf` reading a random value. try `printf("%d + %d = %d\n", 1, 3, 1 + 3);`

Comment: @MarshallLee you can accept the answers as correct answer and vote up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know what you did wrong already, so to explain what your particular implementation of C probably did:

When you call `printf`, a new stack frame is pushed to the call stack. The call stack is a last in first out structure with one 'frame' per called function. So if `main` called `logStuff` which called `printf` then three consecutive frames would be for main, then logStuff, then printf. When printf returns, it's frame is removed from the structure and execution continues with logStuff.

So a frame usually contains at least the parameters passed to the function and storage for local variables. Those things may be one and the same, it's implementation dependant.

With a variadic function like `printf` there's a stream of unnamed parameters. The bit patterns will be put into an appropriate place in the frame. But C is not a reflective language. Each bit patten doesn't inherently have a meaning: any one could be an integer, a float, or anything else. It also isn't a language that invests in bounds checking. You're trusted to write code that acts correctly.

`printf` determines the types and number of unnamed parameters from the string. So if you've given it false information, it will interpret the bit patterns with something other than their correct meaning and it may think there are fewer or more than are really there.

You told it there were more. So what probably happened was that the parameters were in the equivalent of an array and it read a value from beyond the end of the array. As it's all implementation dependent, that value may have been meant to represent anything. It could be the address of the caller. It could be uninitialised storage for another local variable. It could be bookkeeping. It could be the format string, incorrectly interpreted as an integer.

What it isn't is any reliable value. It may not even always be safe to read.

Answer (score 3):

You are in undefined behavior land... you are telling a variadic function that you have 2 `int` sized params, then you only supply one, you are leaking something from the stack.

Comment: No leaking found, only [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984). (AFAIK, on all implementations variadic functions are caller-cleanup anyway).

Comment: @Deduplicator not leaking in the sense of a memory leak, but a leak as in a information leak.. it is a well known attack that a program should only ever support constant formatters to prevent a format string attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 2):

1) `%d` is a format specifier, it tells the compiler how you want to access the value stored at a particular location.(here as an integer)

2) For every format specifier you need to provide a corresponding variable or a value, otherwise at runtime you will get "garbage" i.e. some random value.
Example :

```
int main()
{
int a = 65;
printf("\na = %d", a); // here the value stored in a is accessed as an integer.
printf("\na = %c", a); // the value inside a is accessed as a character.
return 0;
}
```

In the above example `'%d'` in the first `printf` statement tells the compiler that the value stored in the variable a is to be accessed as an integer. (o/p - 65)

In the second `printf` statement `'%c'` is used to access the same variable as a character.(o/p - A)

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects two numerical parameters to be printed, and you're giving it one.

Expected:

```
printf("%d + %d", <some_num>, <another_num>);
```

You're giving it:

```
printf("%d + %d", <some_num>);
```

Where `<some_num>` is what `1+3` evaluates to. The function expects another argument, but receives garbage instead.

What you should do is

```
printf("%d + %d = %d", 1, 3, 1+3);
```